# Spring-data-redis connection pool not working as I expect

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

This is my first application using spring-data-redis and I think I get the concepts pretty well (I've used JdbcTemplate many times with RDBMS-es in the past). Here's what's happening...

The problem I'm running into is that every time I do a get(key) operation (using a ValueOperations object) a connection is opened and closed which causes an approximately 1/10th second delay (*this is server code, so 1/10th second is substantial*).  Here's the spring XML configuration:

```
<!-- Redis DAO stuff -->
<bean
    id="jedisPoolConfig"
    class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig"
    p:testOnBorrow="true"
    p:testOnReturn="true"
    p:timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
    p:minIdle="2"
    p:maxTotal="30"
    p:maxIdle="10"
  />

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    p:host-name="${redis.url}"
    p:port="${redis.port}"
    p:database="0"
    p:use-pool="true"
    p:pool-config-ref="jedisPoolConfig"
/>

<bean id="stringRedisSerializer"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"
/>

<bean id="redisTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate" 
    p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory"
    p:defaultSerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer"
/>
```

and here is the relevant Java code:

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, String> template;
private ValueOperations<String, String> valOps;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    logger.debug("111111111111111111111111aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    valOps = template.opsForValue();
}

public String getTestVal() {
    logger.debug("getTestVal() function called++++++++++++++++++++");
    Object testVal2 = valOps.get("akey");
    testVal2 = valOps.get("akey");
    testVal2 = valOps.get("akey");
    testVal2 = valOps.get("akey");
    testVal2 = valOps.get("akey");
    testVal2 = valOps.get("akey");

    logger.debug("TestVal2 returned from REdis: " + testVal2);

    return null;
}
```

So the value for the same key is being retrieved six times.  The log output that I see is as follows:

```
13:46:37.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG com.arrow.pricing.dao.RedisDAO - getTestVal() function called++++++++++++++++++++
13:46:37.014 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
13:46:37.344 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
13:46:37.416 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
13:46:37.543 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
13:46:37.616 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
13:46:37.742 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
13:46:37.812 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
13:46:37.940 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
13:46:38.003 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
13:46:38.128 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
13:46:38.201 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
13:46:38.337 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
13:46:38.414 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG com.arrow.pricing.dao.RedisDAO -  TestVal2 returned from REdis: yo mama
```

I thought I had followed the docs on how to set up a connection pool, but when dealing with a performance-oriented platform such as Redis, I would *not* expect this delay I'm seeing.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or hints.

Comment: Those opening and closing the connection logs will be logged in both pooling and non-pooling scenarios. Try to stop validating the connection by removing the `testOn*` configs

Comment: Thanks for your response @AliDehghani.  I'm afraid I still get the same delay.

Comment: Look at `RedisAutoConfiguration` from spring boot it may help you

Comment: generally speaking the debug output you see only gives information about an connection obtained and release. I must admit the naming should better reflect that. The underlying `ConnectionFactory` and `RedisConnection` will use the provided pool nevertheless. Please check connections on server to verify connections open. Feel free to report an issue in [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS).

Comment: @ChristophStrobl thank you for your response.  After more research I am going to follow the advice of Donald Knuth and optimize performance last :-)

Comment: Is there any jira opened for this issue? Or is there any suggestion/workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Based on spring-data-redis-1.7.2.RELEASE

```
if(!isConnectionTransactional(conn, factory)) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Closing Redis Connection");
    }
    conn.close()
}
```

By the log, you could see "Closing Redis Connection" in line 205 and then connection is closed by call **close** method.

We can find that **conn** is implements **RedisConnection**.In this case, the actual class we used is **JedisConnection**.

see code start at line 256.

```
public void close() throws DataAccessExeception {
    super.close();
    // return the connection to the pool
    if (pool != null) {
        ...balabala 
    }
}
```

The connection is back to the pool.
Now we know that **RedisConnectionUtils** alaways show the log "Closing Redis Connection" even used pool